# How do I open an Electron app with Cypress

Tags: electron, cypress

Is there a way to use cypress to open an electron desktop application?  I know Cypress can run within an electron browser, but my application is an actual app that is downloaded, installed and run from the desktop.

Comment: There is a blog post in cypress blog which discusses in detail how you can use cypress for Electron Application. May be this would help you - https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/09/26/testing-electron-js-applications-using-cypress-alpha-release/